# How to list and probably detach file explorer plugins?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list Explorer extensions and disable them?](https://superuser.com/questions/286000/how-to-list-explorer-extensions-and-disable-them)

I know that there are possible plugins for main windows file explorer. These plugins can contain bugs which will cause entire explorer freeze or crash. Is it possible to list all those plugins and disable them as it can be done with IE?

Comment: No, but you can probably find out what's hooking into Explorer using something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: How? Spawned processes are not plugins. Plugins may be listed as threads, but what to do if I see some DLL there?

Comment: Perhaps [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) might help. Also see [How to list Explorer extensions and disable them?](http://superuser.com/questions/286000/how-to-list-explorer-extensions-and-disable-them)