# How to fix explorer freezing when accessing usb?

Tags: windows, usb, windows-explorer, freeze, debug

very often my explorer freezes when accessing usb (sometimes I have to restart it, sometimes the not responding goes away in a few seconds) and today was the worst case (might have been cause i was multitasking) I was downloading stuff with qbittorrent, had chrome open with about 2 tabs and when i accessed my usb my explorer completely froze, i tried restarting with task manager but didnt work, so i CHOKED THE PC (hold down power button) and am now doing a chkdsk scan on my usb

Comment: I would guess either a bad USB stick or a [third party shell extension](https://superuser.com/questions/286000/how-to-list-explorer-extensions-and-disable-them).

Comment: aight, probs bad stick but not gonna throw it away, it is TRUE 128GB (not fake ebay scam bs) and I have lots of data on there